# How can I have Awk to also show field separator?

Tags: bash, awk

I want to use awk to get a more clean output of some files in a directory. My problem is that they can look different and that I also want to see the separator.

```
 name.name.name.name.PDTV.x264-DEADPOOL.mp4
 name.name.name.name.PDTV.x264-C4TV.mp4
 name.S07E10.HDTV.x264-ASAP.mp4
 name.name.S03E11.HDTV.x264-ASAP.mp4
 name.name.S03E12.HDTV.x264-EVOLVE.mp4
 name.name.2x01.HDTV_x264-FoV.[VTV].mp4
```

So far I have been using `awk -F"[xE][0-9]" '{print $1}'<<<$list` and similar but it will output...

```
 name.S07
 name.name.S03
 name.name.2
```

I want it to also output the FS or in this case E10. As in..

```
 name.S07E10
 name.name.S03E11
 name.name.2x01
```

Is there a way to have awk show the field separator or can this be done in another way?

Comment: Du you like separator to be one letter and one number, or du you like one letter and one or more number.  What about the two first line? they will hit on `x264` with this regex `[xE][0-9]`

Comment: I didn't care what came after the season and episode number. That should just be blank and your solution below did that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This `gnu awk` may work:

```
awk -v RS="([xE][0-9][0-9])|\n" '{$1=$1} /name/ {print $0,RT}' file
name.name.name.name.PDTV. x26
name.name.name.name.PDTV. x26
name.S07 E10
name.name.S03 E11
name.name.S03 E12
name.name.2 x01
```

Here I use `RT` instead of `RS`.

---

Here is another way to do it with `awk`

```
awk ' {f=match($0,/[xE][0-9][0-9]/)} f {print substr($0,1,f-1),substr($0,f,3)}' file
name.name.name.name.PDTV. x26
name.name.name.name.PDTV. x26
name.S07 E10
name.name.S03 E11
name.name.S03 E12
name.name.2 x01
```

Comment: +1 for the `RT` approach (`RT`, a GNU extension, stands for record terminator and contains the actual, literal record separator that was encountered). To match the OP's sample output format, consider using e.g. `print $0 RT` (concatenation) instead of `print $0, RT`.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using `sed` instead, which simplifies things:

```
sed -En 's/^(.+)([xE][0-9]+)\..+/\1\2/p' file
```

Note that this will ignore lines that don't contain an episode number, as your sample output suggests.

If you want to process *all* lines - even those not containing an episode number - use:

```
sed -E 's/^(.+)\.[HP]DTV.*/\1/' file
```

This will simply strip the suffix starting with `.HDTV` or `.PDTV`.

(Compatibility note: Using `-E` instead of `-r` makes the command work on both Linux and OSX.)

Comment: I actually ended up using the `'..TV'` as it solved my problem better. Thanks for noticing that. Jotne got the accepted as he solved it with Awk and that was my original question.